# Convolution of a probability distribution with another function is a quadratic polynomial

Tags: real-analysis, probability-distributions, convolution

Convolution of a probability distribution function(which is never zero) with an analytic function, f(x), is  a quadratic polynomial. can we say that f(x) must be polynomial too? If not can you come up with a counterexample? I have to mention that we do not know if f(x) has Fourier transform or not.

thanks

Comment: "Convolution of a probability distribution with a analytic function". For a [convolution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution) you need two functions on the same domain. A probability distribution is actually function on sets. Don't you mean PDF?

Comment: You are right. I mean a PDF.

Comment: @drhab Huh? A probability distribution is a measure. The notion of the convolution of a measure with a function is perfectly standard: $f*\mu(x)=\int f(x-t)\,d\mu(t)$.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich I admit that my conception of convolution was too narrow. Thank you for making it broader.

Answer (score 0):

This is an answer to the original version of the question, regarding the convolution of a probability distribution with an analytic function.

Say $X$ is a random variable with $P(X=0)=P(X=\pi)=0$. So the distribution of $X$ is $\mu=(\delta_0+\delta_\pi)/2$, where $\delta_t$ denotes a point mass at $t$. Let $f(t)=\sin(t)$. Then $\mu*f=0$.

In detail: $$\mu*f(x)=\int f(x-t)\,d\mu(t)=(f(x)+f(x-\pi))/2=0.$$